# Converting JSON into CSV using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have JSON data :

```
u'{"result":[{"timestamp":1356843600000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":0}},{"timestamp":1356930000000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":15672}},{"timestamp":1357016400000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":13646}},{"timestamp":1357102800000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":14301}
```

Now this needs to be written into a new csv file.
I got the 'response' as JSON

```
response = requests.get(end_point,params=query_params);

# pprint.pprint(response.text)


data = json.loads(response.text)


f=csv.writer(open('test_1.csv','wb+'))

for item in data['result']:
 f.writerow(item['timestamp']['stream:sentimentNeutral'].values())
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\codevOne.py", line 26, in <module>
    f.writerow(item['timestamp']['stream:sentimentNeutral'].values())
TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

please correct my mistake.I feel that I am struggling in traversing a dict in a dict.
The result I expect is a file named 'test.csv' with a *timestamp* row and corresponding *stream:sentimentNeutral* value

Comment: isn't stream:sentimentNeutral unde values key and not timestamp?

Comment: `item['timestamp']['stream:sentimentNeutral']` is just a `long` number, not itself a dictionary. What are you trying to achieve - what output did you expect?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to convert response (a JSON object) into a csv file.
@Mark I tried `code` f.writerow(item['stream:sentimentNeutral'].values())`code`
I got this error`code`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\codevOne.py", line 26, in <module>
    f.writerow(item['stream:sentimentNeutral'].values())
KeyError: 'stream:sentimentNeutral'
`code`

Comment: Could you add expected CSV content?

Answer (score 0):

Edit : add source of a complete test
This could do the job (if I correctly understood what you want) :

```
for item in data['result']:
  f.writerow((item['timestamp'], item['values']['stream:sentimentNeutral']))
```

It gives a csv file consisting of lines `timestamp, stream:sentimentNeutral`

Here is a complete test with your data :

```
import pprint
import csv
import json

resp = u'{"result":[{"timestamp":1356843600000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":0}},{"timestamp":1356930000000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":15672}},{"timestamp":1357016400000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":13646}},{"timestamp":1357102800000,"values":{"stream:sentimentNeutral":14301}}]}'
data = json.loads(resp)
pprint.pprint(data)
with open('test_1.csv','wb+') as fd:
    f = csv.writer(fd)
    for item in data['result']:
        f.writerow((item['timestamp'], item['values']['stream:sentimentNeutral']))
```

The output of `pprint` is :

```
{u'result': [{u'timestamp': 1356843600000L,
              u'values': {u'stream:sentimentNeutral': 0}},
             {u'timestamp': 1356930000000L,
              u'values': {u'stream:sentimentNeutral': 15672}},
             {u'timestamp': 1357016400000L,
              u'values': {u'stream:sentimentNeutral': 13646}},
             {u'timestamp': 1357102800000L,
              u'values': {u'stream:sentimentNeutral': 14301}}]}
```

and here is the content of `test_1.csv`

```
1356843600000,0
1356930000000,15672
1357016400000,13646
1357102800000,14301
```

Comment: The code that I used is this:
`code`
response = requests.get(end_point,params=query_params);
# pprint.pprint(response.text)
linewriter = csv.writer(wfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

obj = json.loads(response.text)
mydecoder_cDA = json.JSONDecoder(response.text)
data=mydecoder_cDA.decode(response.text)


#data = json.loads(response.text)



f=csv.writer(open('test_2.csv','wb+'))

for item in data['result']:
 f.writerow((item['timestamp'], item['values']['stream:sentimentNeutral']))

`code`
This is creating an empty csv file.

Comment: I've just edited my post to give you the complete test I did on an Ubuntu box running Python 2.7.3 (`with` construct ensures file is properly closed whatever could happen)

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code `item['timestamp']` is a numeric value, for example, in the first loop, the value of it is 1356843600000 rather than a dict.

You should use:

```
for item in data['result']:
    timestamp = item['timestamp']
    value = item['values']['stream:sentimentNeutral']
    f.writerow([timestamp, value])
```

Comment: That is printing an empty excel!